# C struct static

Tags: c

I look through a C source (pjsip) and I find this sctucture. I don't know how to conceive.

```
static struct user_agent
{
    pjsip_module     mod;
    pj_pool_t       *pool;
    pjsip_endpoint  *endpt;
    pj_mutex_t      *mutex;
    pj_hash_table_t *dlg_table;
    pjsip_ua_init_param  param;
    struct dlg_set   free_dlgset_nodes;

} mod_ua = 
{
  {
    NULL, NULL,         /* prev, next.          */
    { "mod-ua", 6 },        /* Name.                */
    -1,             /* Id               */
    PJSIP_MOD_PRIORITY_UA_PROXY_LAYER,  /* Priority     */
    &mod_ua_load,       /* load()               */
    NULL,           /* start()              */
    NULL,           /* stop()               */
    &mod_ua_unload,     /* unload()             */
    &mod_ua_on_rx_request,  /* on_rx_request()          */
    &mod_ua_on_rx_response, /* on_rx_response()         */
    NULL,           /* on_tx_request.           */
    NULL,           /* on_tx_response()         */
    &mod_ua_on_tsx_state,   /* on_tsx_state()           */
  }
};
```

Comment: Just do what comes naturally.

Comment: Like Kev said: it's not the type (`struct user_agent`) that's static, it's the variable (`mod_ua`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a particularly clear question but what I think you're having a problem with is that the struct is being declared and used in the same statement. How about:

```
struct user_agent {
    ....
}

static struct user_agent mod_ua = ....
```

That any clearer?

K

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without the definitions of the structures, but I think what's happening is that the `mod` member (which is of type `pjsip_module`) is being initialised, and the other members of `mod_ua` are not explicitly initialised (which means they'll be set to zero, because that's what happens when some members are initialised and not others).  The inner set of braces is the clue.  Have a look at the definition of `pjsip_module` - does it match the values you have?